# Partitioning an Arch-Linux over multiple drives

Tags: arch-linux, partition

in the last days I heard of Wine 3.0. Also I heard of PCI passthrough and so on.
Because of some reasons I want go away from Windows.
I'm using linux (Ubuntu/Debian) at work for four years now.
Now I want to build an Arch-Linux setup at home.

Some background to me:
I'm a Softwaredeveloper (mainlanguages: Java, JavaScript)
I don't play so much anymore, I want to play Overwatch mainly
I'm german native speaker (sry when my english isn't so well)

## Current Setup

Windows 10

SSD 256GB

- 450MB Recovery
- 100MB EFI
- 213GB Windows (C:)
- 871MB Another recovery (Don't know were this comes from ^^')
- 24GB SSD Fallback

500GB HDD

- Home 465GB (D:)

2TB HDD

- Programms 1863GB (E:)

1TB HDD

- Files 931GB (F:)

2TB HDD

- Steam 1862GB (S:)

## Planned Setup

Arch-Linux

(size, label, dir, drive/partition)

SSD 256GB /dev/sda

- 512MB BOOT `/boot` /dev/sda1
- 255GB ROOT `/` /dev/sda2

500GB HDD /dev/sdb

- 449GB HOME `/home` /dev/sdb1
- 16GB SWAP /dev/sdb2

2TB HDD /dev/sdc

- 1863GB PROGRAMS `/opt` & `/var` /dev/sdc1

Question to that: can I make one partition and put `/opt` and `/var` into this?
Also maybe `/usr`? [systemd separate-usr-is-broken](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/separate-usr-is-broken/)

1TB HDD /dev/sde

- 931GB FILES /dev/sde1 **or** NTFS and let it as it is

Not really a plan with this
I used it for recorded video material

2TB HDD /dev/sdd

- 1862GB STEAM `/steam` /dev/sdd1

Can I make a directory on `/steam`? otherwise is it possible to do `/opt/steam` on this drive?

## Further Questions

### /data

What is it? Should I put this into another drive than SSD?

### did I forgot something?

Comment: With such a huge root volume why would you want to put `/var` on another volume?

Comment: @HaukeLaging I heard about `/var` contains content like `/logs` and `/www` and I think it is not so well when every day apps write logs on my SSD. So I think I want to outsource `/var`

Comment: That amount of data is (on a usual system) irrelevant compared to the size of your drive. However: You may safely put e.g. `/var/logs/apache2` and `/var/www` on an LVM LV. You could even put the whole `/var/log` onto a dedicated LV but it may happen that something gets logged there before the LV is mounted.

Comment: Can you clear out what you mean by 'logged there before the LV is mounted'? Why and when can this happen? Isn't it a no go for using LVM?
PS: I do not have enough reputation for now to vote your answers, but you've really helped me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put `/opt` and `/var` into the same volume by making it a btrfs volume and creating subvolumes for both. You can also chose just any file system and use bind mounts.

But the probably best solution is to use LVM and not use all the available space. LVM logical volumes and aeveral file systems (at least ext4 and btrfs) can be enlarged online i.e. a mounted file system can grow.

I like to have a second, small linux partition where I install a maintenance Linux (text mode only). That way you do not need a separate boot medium for many problems.

Comment: So I read a little bit about LVM. So I can have on my SSD boot and root and on ALL other HDDs an LVM and partitioning this logically? I don't know if I want this :/ It is not a RAID. I had a setup like my Windows in multiple hard drives a long time and I like to know which content is on which HDD.

I think I like the `bind mounts` way the most. Has it any disadvantage?

Comment: @Shinigami You can even boot from LVM. Usually you do not need a separate `/boot` volume with EFI anyway. With today's kernel and initrd sized I have seen 500MiB `/boot` volumes run full. Why wouldn't you know on which disk your data is? I do not like about bind mounts that they are not obvious in `/proc/mounts`. And they may be unexpected. I have often experienced failure with offline dist upgrades with unusual mount setups because the installer was not prepared for symlinks or bind mounts.

Comment: I can also give /boot 1 or 2 GB, this isn't the really problem. How can I know which data is on which disk when I have a LVM on all my HDDs? Or do you mean that I create a LVM on each HDD? Can you clear this setup out for me? That would be awesome. I think LVM stretched over multiple HDDs isn't a good thing, because if one HDD breaks, I lose all my data instead of only in example my programs.

Comment: @Shinigami I thought of one VG per drive.